# Graphical bug viewing PDF in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, pdf

So, I'm looking at a PDF in Safari 12.0 off JSTOR. And it appears like this:

[image]

Which definitely isn't how it should be rendered. But more concerningly, this persists with a number of PDFs from ScienceDirect, Elsevier, and other academic journal aggregators.

This problem doesn't persist in Chrome for the same documents.

Has this problem been encountered before, and are there any fixes?

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are using?

Comment: I'm running Mojave 10.14

Comment: Can you share the URLs for the offending files?

Comment: This case was a JSTOR file, https://www.jstor.com/stable/pdf/40599878.pdf

Comment: As much as I hate the app, how does Adobe Reader display the file? If it's the same I would lean towards a damaged file.

Comment: It displays fine in Preview and Chrome. The document isn't damaged.

Comment: I've been seeing the same thing. Here is a [non-JSTOR example](https://mises-media.s3.amazonaws.com/We_2.pdf?file=1&type=document) which produces the same effect. Also on 10.14.

Comment: Both of the links here displays fine on my machine, High Sierra and Safari.

Comment: Problem has disappeared for both links in Safari 12.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is a bug and the comments confirm others can reproduce it. Given this, please tell Apple. Only Apple can fix the underlying bug.

## Report to Apple

Use the feedback form to [report this bug](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) to Apple. Alternatively, if you have access, you can use [Bug Reporter](https://bugreporter.apple.com) to tell Apple's engineering teams directly.